# background color is not working

Tags: css

Im trying to apply background color for whole block c_date.. but its not working.. I tried clear, block everything..

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vjfrnnxL/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="c_date"> <span class="c_day">30</span>
 <span class="c_month">Jun</span>
 <span class="c_year">2009</span>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.c_date {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    color: #999;
    margin: -0px 0 0 0;
    background:#999 !important;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    clear:both;
}
.c_day, .c_month, .c_year {
    position: absolute;
}
.c_day {
    font-size: 14px;
    top: 10px;
}
.c_month {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.c_year {
    top: 9px;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 9px;
    rotation: -90deg !important;
    /* ** Hacks ** */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: Your `c_date` block is rendering with 2px height. You need to cleanup your markup, Try adding some height(say 50px) to it and you'll see the background color.

Comment: this is because use absolut postion for .c_day, .c_month, .c_year, if add height for c_date every thing is ok

Comment: you are using `position:absolute` on your span elements. this takes them out of being registered as elements effecting the parent `div`

Comment: And don't use same color and backgorund color,

Comment: Thanks Samy.. if I specify height, its working.. :-)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.c_date {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    color: #999;
    margin: -0px 0 0 0;
    background-color: #999 !important;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    clear:both;
    height: 30px; //change to your needs

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because your c_date div height is 2px [image] (the reason is position:absolute; in your other containers).
So you can fix it by adding height to c_date style or changing position property of child elements in it.

Comment: **`+1`** I think you should write an answer too.

Answer (score 4):

This can actually be done without the need to `position:absolute` the day and month spans. This will mean that the height of your `c_date` element is actually relative to the height of the stacked day and month elements.

I took the liberty of fixing up some of the CSS code that didnt need to be there from your demo too :)

**HTML**

```
<div class="c_date">
    <span class="c_month">Jun</span><br />
    <span class="c_day">30</span>
    <span class="c_year">2009</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.c_date {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    color: #999;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background:#00F !important;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    font-size:0; /* set to 0 so that <br/> and spaces between <span> dont effect height/spacing */
}
.c_year {
    position: absolute;
}
.c_day {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    text-align:center;
}
.c_month {
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-align:center;
}
.c_year {
    top: 9px;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 9px;
    /* ** Hacks ** */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vjfrnnxL/28/)**